# Install command if command doesn't exist

Tags: bash, shell-script, make

I have this set up in a `Makefile`.

```
ARG_2 := $(word 2, $(MAKECMDGOALS))

command_exist=command -v $(1) >/dev/null 2>&1
command_not_exist=! command -v $(1) >/dev/null 2>&1

npmig:
    $(call command_not_exist,npm) && echo 'npm is not installed'
    $(call command_not_exist,ied) && npm install ied
    $(call command_not_exist,$(ARG_2)) && ied install $(ARG_2) -g
```

The general idea is that I can run something like `make npmig json`, and if `npm` is not installed I will get an actual error. If `ied` is not installed it will be installed, and finally `ied` will install `json`.

- After the first line, and if the `npm` check fails the process should exit.
- After the second `ied` should be installed regardless if it was installed, or (hopefully) just installed.
- After the third `json` should be installed regardless if it was installed, or (hopefully) just installed.

This does not work. The code that checks if the command exists will throw and error and the whole recipe will exit. I need a way to control flow this recipe so that it exits when I need it to and continues when I need it to.

Comment: I would be pretty upset if I ran `make` and it did something outside the scope of *building* a package, like installing other packages. What's wrong with a useful message like `echo 'foo is not installed, I can't continue. You can install it with the command: bar install foo'`?

Comment: @drewbenn I'm planning on using this `Makefile` as a place for all of my bash scripts and would like to easily be able to clone the `Makefile` across systems and not have to guess what deps are installed.

Comment: do you have an actual question?  or are you just telling us what your Makefile contains?

Comment: @cas I updated the question. This doesn't work as intended and I'm looking for a way to make this idea work.

Comment: How is this unclear what I'm asking for, it's in the title...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already familiar, you should take a close look at [pkgsrc](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/introduction.html). `pkgsrc` is a powerful tool that is actively growing, broadly supported, and does this exactly this type of package management.

You can find an example makefile [here](https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/examples.html) to get you started.

Comment: That just looks like a package manager within Make. I'm looking for some way to install dependencies from any package manager. `npm`, `gem`, `pip`, whatever!